# Include view from another module inside my current view

Tags: codeigniter

The structure is as follows:

```
modules/school/config
modules/school/controllers
modules/school/controllers/form.php
modules/school/models
modules/school/views
modules/school/views/form.php

modules/univ/config
modules/univ/controllers
modules/univ/controllers/form.php
modules/univ/models
modules/univ/views
modules/univ/views/form.php
```

Now, I don't like the school form anymore, so I want to include university form inside the school view. How do I do that?

```
$this->load->view('../univ/form'); // does not work
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you use HMVC by wiredesignz

in this case you've 2 possibilites

direct call

```
$this->load->view('univ/form');
```

or via `modules::run`

create in your univ/form  a function where you load this view - e.g.

```
class Form extends MX_Controller
{

    public funciton view()
    {
        $this->load->view('form');
    }
}
```

and in your School Class you simply call

```
class School extends MX_Controller
{

    public funciton view()
    {
        echo modules::run('univ/form/view');
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you `echo` with `modules::run` ?

Comment: `modules::run()` is designed for returning view partials, and it will return buffered output (a view) from a controller.

Comment: Actually this is the correct answer. But it does work in my code, and idk why.

Comment: you might take a look @your log file under `/application/logs/` there has to be something if an error occurs... (another thing, you tried to edit my answer by writing `Modules::run` according to Wiredesignz this is wrong) take a look here https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc

Comment: I edited because I found that code somewhere else in my code, a working code. That's how I knew your answer is correct.

Comment: Maybe you can leave both, in case someone will have a problem.